# Does sscanf() support "recursive" buffer?

Tags: c, scanf

I make some research in order to look for the `sscanf()` source code . But I could not find the answer to my question.

when we use `sscanf()` in this way:

```
char str[50] = "5,10,15";
int x;
sscanf(str,"%d,%s",&x,str);
```

Does sscanf() support "recursive" buffer `str` ?

Comment: Reading from, and writing to the same memory area at the same time is usually not a good idea.

Comment: I know this. but it could be supported by the sscanf function. and that why I m looking for.  May be the scanf does not have problem with that. and this will allow me to optimize my code. I will not have to add another buffer and make copy ...

Comment: BTW I tested it in a small program and I did not get any problem in the execution. But I want a confirmation from some one who knows the code

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html has a `restrict` on the source string. Passing another pointer to `str` in the argument list would, I think, violate the restrict promise, but I'm not entirely sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't break from self modifying buffer. But to make it (tail)recursive, you'd have to read to the end of the string.
The code fragment:

```
char str[]="5,10,15";
int a[10]={0},x = 0; 
while (sscanf(str,"%d,%s",a+ x++,str)>1);
```

reads all the integers.

Since this is not really recursive and the string to be read doesn't overwrite the asciiz in the string, I believe this is "safe" in the meaning: only try this at home.

Comment: Neat trick. Clearly less efficient than using %n and looping with increasing offset into str, which is probably what the question demands, but it's a good idea. You'd have to implement sscanf in a fairly silly way for this not to work, I feel.

Answer (score 3):

scanf family functions read the format specifiers and do the conversion one-by-one. In your example code:

```
char str[50] = "5,10,15";
int x;
sscanf(str,"%d,%s",&x,str);
```

It may work because it reads in an integer first and another c-string. No problem here as original `str` is over-written with the new value.

But consider the following:

```
char str[50] = "5 10 15";
int x;
sscanf(str,"%s %d",str, &x);
```

It first reads `5` from the original value and overwrites `str` and subsequent format specifier `%d` will have nothing to read from `str` as the end of `str` has been reached due  to the nul-termination for the previous `%s` read.

It's just a counter example to show it's a bad idea and won't work. So you can say this is going to invoke undefined behaviour at some point or cause other problems.

Comment: Agreed. And even if correctly used, a recursive sscanf() is likely to trigger all the alarms for the next programmer who maintains your code, making them duplicate this non-trivial deduction. Respect your colleagues' time. Keep your code readable and don't make them think!

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would advise against this. If it works once it doesn't mean, that it will in all corner cases. To be really sure, you'd have to check sources for the very implementation you are using. If you want it to be portable, forget about it right away, unless you see it written in the libc specs as a guaranteed behaviour. Use `strchr()` to find the next delimiter and update the string pointer to point at the next character.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `strtok()` solved an almost identical problem I had, namely, using `sscanf()` recursively to extract the contents of a `char*`  (a list of double's separated by a space, e.g. `"1.00 2.01 ..."`) into a double array (e.g. `array[1]=1.00`, `array[2]=2.01`, ...).

The following might help, if I believe I understand your issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char str[]= "5,10,15";
    char* token;

    int x[3];

    token = strtok(str, ",");

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){

            sscanf(token, "%d", &x[i]);

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");

    }

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) printf("%d\n", x[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

On running, it produces:

```
5
10
15
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ for a useful description of `strtok()`.